# ¿Cómo llamo a una función JQuery desde otro fichero .js?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un fichero llamado crear-orden.js desde el cual quiero agregar una alerta en el DOM.
Para eso coloco lo siguiente:

`$(document).ready(agregaAlerta());`

La función agregaAlerta(); se encuentra en otro fichero llamado crear-orden.encabezado.js.
En el cual tengo lo siguiente:

`function agregaAlerta(){`
  `$(".orden-de-compra").before(`
   `'<div class="alert alert-primary text-center" role="alert">'+`
     `'Esto es una Prueba'+`
   `'</div>');`
 `};`

¿Cómo hago para poder utilizar la funcion agregaAlerta() en el fichero crear-orden.js?

PD: Estoy organizado mi código y para eso estoy encapsulando y separando código en distintos ficheros .js.

Comment: ¿Ambos archivos están incluidos en el documento? ¿La función `agregaAlerta` es global o esta dentro de un [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE), etc.?

Comment: Si, ambos archivos estan incluidos en el documento entre <script></script>. La función está escrita en el fichero crear-orden.encabezado.js tal como se muestra.

Comment: Entonces simplemente deberías cargar primero el `script crear-orden.encabezado.js`  y luego el `script crear-orden.js`

Comment: Perfecto Gracias! me funciono. Y como aplico esto con un IIFE?

Comment: Usando `IIFE` sería un poco mas complicado, te diría que no vale la pena enroscarse con eso

Answer (score 0):

Se debe definir en el index.php un modulo de entrada. Esto se hace de la siguiente manera:

`<script type="module" src="entrada.js"></script>`

Luego tendremos el archivo que "alimenta" a entrada.js, en este caso lo llamo funciones.js. En dicho archivo tendremos una función la cual tendremos que exportar.

`export function prueba(){`
 `\..`
`}`

Luego, para poder utilizar prueba() en el archivo entrada.js debemos realizar un import:

`import { prueba } from './funciones.js';`

Y de esta manera podremos utilizar la función como lo hacemos habitualmente.

`prueba();`